# Normalization made my queries slower

Tags: mysql, sql

Before normalization I had a column called `genre`and it contained values like "Action, Thriller, Comedy"

Now I have normalized the genre column by creating `genre` and `movie2genre` tables.

The problem now is my queries are more complicated and are actually **slower**

These two queries basically search for movies that are action and thriller

**Old query**

```
select title, genre from movie where genre like '%action%' and genre like '%thriller%'
0.062 sec duration / 0.032 sec fetch
```

**New Query**

```
SELECT movie.title, movie.genre
FROM Movie 
Where 
EXISTS (
 select *
 from movie2genre 
 JOIN Genre on Genre.id = movie2genre.GenreId 
 where Movie.id = movie2genre.MovieId 
   and genre in ('action', 'thriller')
)
0.328 sec duration / 0.078 sec fetch
```

Am I doing something wrong?

More info:

**Movie**

```
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID          | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Title       | varchar(345)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
  ETC....
```

**Genre**

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| genreid | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name    | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+.
```

**movie2genre**

```
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| movieid | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| genreid | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Did you set an index on genreid in movie2genre ?

Comment: Both the queries are different, in `first one` you are having an `and` cond, while in `second` query you are having an `in clause` which is equals to `or` clause and hence the `difference.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this without correlated Queries (Please check the execution plan of both queries if you are concerned about the performance) also Make sure you have proper indexes on your new table.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM movie2genre mg, Genre g, Movie m
 WHERE m.id = mg.MovieId
 AND   g.id = mg.GenreId 
 AND   g.genre in ('action', 'thriller')
```

Comment: This is faster but i am trying to find movies who have atleast action and thriller in their genre. meaning they have to be action and thriller, they can be action thriller and comedy but they need to have action and thriller at the least

Comment: Can you share the sample data in table. Please add it into Question.

Answer (score 0):

First, your two queries are *not* the same.  The newer version does an `or` rather than an `and`, so the difference in time could simply be returning a larger result set.  In addition, your new query refers to `movie.genre`, a column that wouldn't exist in a normalized database.

You seem to be asking for:

```
select m.title
from Movie m
where exists (select 1
              from movie2genre m2g JOIN
                   Genre g
                   on g.id = m2g.GenreId 
              where m.id = m2g.MovieId and g.genre = 'action'
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from movie2genre m2g JOIN
                   Genre g
                   on g.id = m2g.GenreId 
              where m.id = m2g.MovieId and g.genre = 'thriller'
             );
```

Admittedly, you probably will not think this solves the "complication" problem.  Leaving that aside, you need to have indexes for this to work well.  Do you have the "obvious" indexes of:  `movie2genre(MovieId, GenreId)` and `genre(GenreId)`?

Second, your data is not particularly large (judging by the duration for the queries).  So, a full table scan may be more efficient than the joining and filtering with these tables.  As the database grows, the normalized approach will often be faster.

A more equivalent query is:

```
select m.title, group_concat(g.genre)
from movies m join
     movie2genre m2g
     on m.movieid = m2g.movieid join
     genre g
     on g.genreid = m2g.genreid
group by m.title
having sum(g.genre = 'action') > 0 and sum(g.genre = 'thriller') > 0;
```

Because of the nature of your particular query -- you need to fetch all genres on a movie so you cannot filter on them -- this particular query is probably going to perform less well than the unnormalized version.

By the way, normalization is more about keeping data *consistent* than about speeding queries.  Normalized databases require more join operations.  Indexes can help performance, but there is still work in doing the join.  In some cases, the tables themselves are bigger than the unnormalized forms.  And, normalized databases may require aggregation where none is required for non-normalized database.  All of these can affect performance, which is why in many decision support architectures, the central database is normalized but the application-specific databases are not.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are vitally important when doing joins (and sub queries tend to lose the indexing).
There are 2 ways I would suggest trying.

Firstly you join movies to movie2genre, and then one join to genre for each one you are checking. Well indexed this should be fast.

```
SELECT movie.title, 
        movie.genre
FROM Movie 
INNER JOIN movie2genre
ON Movie.id = movie2genre.MovieId 
INNER JOIN Genre G1
ON G1.id = movie2genre.GenreId 
AND G1.genre = 'action'
INNER JOIN Genre G2
ON G2.id = movie2genre.GenreId 
AND G2.genre = 'thriller'
```

An alternative is to use IN, and use the aggregate COUNT function to check that the number of genres found is the same as the number expected.

```
SELECT movie.title, 
        movie.genre
FROM Movie 
INNER JOIN movie2genre
ON Movie.id = movie2genre.MovieId 
INNER JOIN Genre 
ON Genre.id = movie2genre.GenreId 
AND Genre.genre IN ('action', 'thriller')
GROUP BY movie.title, movie.genre
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT genreid) = 2
```

I would prefer the 1st solution, but it is a bit more complicated to set up the SQL for in code (ie, the SQL varies greatly depending on the number of genres), and potentially is limited by the max number of table joins if you are checking for lots of genres.